# Generating DSM and DEM from processed LiDAR (TIFF) on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: dem, arcgis-pro, lidar

I have a "processed" LiDAR that is available as TIFF, I do not know how it was processed although I've read about the method of converting a LAS dataset to Mosaic, terrain, etc.

I was basically just given the tiff below to generate a DSM and DEM, it is basically just flat.

I have searched on how to create dem and dsm surfaces from the lidar raster but can't find anything about it, although there's information of accomplishing that if it were a point clouds.

So how can I possibly create DSM and DEM from the Lidar tiff?

[image: lidar.tiff]

Comment: What do you mean flat? It looks like a DSM already as its showing elevation values.

Comment: Flat means it doesn't seem to show continuity ... anyway if that's a dsm, how do get the dem?

Comment: A DEM is a "bare earth" DSM. To get a DEM from a DSM, you subtract the heights of the buildings, trees, etc, but you need to calculate/model/figure out somehow the heights of these features, not something that is easily done... Alternatively use the original LIDAR point cloud data and LIDAR software to classify the points into ground and non-ground points and use those to generate DEM and DSM rasters.

Comment: Thanks you. I don't have the original LIDAR, I was hoping there was a way to generate them from the dataset I have